# Are both the "special" and the "needs" in "special needs" adjectives?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech

In the sentence, "she is a special needs child" (referring to someone with a disability), what parts of speech are the words "special needs"? Are both adjectives on their own, or do they only form an adjective together (and what is that called)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Special needs* is an **attributive adjective** (an **adjectival phrase**). In fact, it could be written *special-needs*.